# изменение страницы после успешной авторизации пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

на главной странице есть иконка авторизации (блок .auth_icon). после того, как пользователь авторизовался, необходимо заменить на иконку выхода (.icForRegistrUsers). Я не понимаю как и где необходимо выполнить проверку на успешную авторизацию и как заменить иконки.[проект на GitHub](https://github.com/vitarunaeva/vlgplace.git)

```html
<div class="auth_icon">
                <a href="#popup-auth" class="js-popup-open"><img src="./public/images/icons/enter.svg" height="35px" width="35px" alt="authorization_icon" title="Авторизоваться"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="icForRegistrUsers">
                <a href="/profile"><img src="./public/images/icons/avatar.svg" height="35px" width="35px" alt="avatar_icon" title="Перейти в профиль"></a>
                <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-logout">Выйти</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас должен с сервера приходить флаг, который означает, что пользователь вошел в систему. По этому флагу можно подменить иконку, или же просто одну иконку скрывать, а другую показывать. Что-то типо такого

```
const promiseReturnAutorizeFlag = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    autorizeUserAutorize().then((autorizeFlag) => {
    resolve(autorizeFlag);
    }).catch((error) => {
    reject(error);
    });
});
};

const showAutorizeIcon = () => {
    const noUserIconSel = document.querySelector('img.no-autorize-icon'); //в HTML разметке есть селектор с неавторизованной иконкой и классом "no-autorize-icon" <img class="no-autorize-icon" src="yourIcon.svg">.
    const autorizeUserIconSel = document.querySelector('img.autorize-icon'); //в HTML разметке есть селектор с неавторизованной иконкой и классом "autorize-icon" <img class="no-autorize-icon" src="yourIcon.svg">. 

    noUserIconSel.style.display = 'none';
    autorizeUserIconSel.style.display = 'block';
};


promise().then((autorizeFlag) => {
    if (autorizeFlag === false) return;

    showAutorizeIcon();
}).catch((error) => {
    console.info(error);
});
```